# What replaced RoutedHttpService in Spray

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I've been following [this blog post about Spray and Akka](http://blog.eigengo.com/blog_posts/akka-spray) as it seems to be a reasonable way to separate out the implementation from the routing in an async service. However, this post being > 6 months old the Spray API seems to have changed and the `RoutedHttpService` it uses about half way down is nowhere to be found.

I'm fairly new to Scala and very new to Spray, and the Spray docs are at best obtuse, so I've been struggling what to replace that bit of the code with.

A couple of questions then:

1. Is the approach outlined in this post actually sensible?
2. If the answer to (1) is yes, then what should `RoutedHttpService` be replaced with?
3. If the answer to (1) is no, then is there some other docs of 'the right way' to do Spray?

---

For easy reference, the bit of code in question is this:

```
trait Api extends RouteConcatenation {
  this: CoreActors with Core =>

  private implicit val _ = system.dispatcher

  val routes =
    new RegistrationService(registration).route ~
    new MessengerService(messenger).route

  val rootService = system.actorOf(Props(new RoutedHttpService(routes))) // :-(  
}
```

Comment: The spray-template project also gives a very simple way to structure your code where you might want to start from: https://github.com/spray/spray-template/blob/on_spray-can_1.3/src/main/scala/com/example/MyService.scala

Comment: Thanks @jrudolph, yes that's definitely simpler but I like the separation between the logic and routing in the mentioned post which should make testing much simpler. Once I've got into Spray a bit more I think it's fantastic (thanks!) and the docs for directives etc. are really pretty good, but I and a few others have struggles with how to bootstrap a 'real' project with tests and the like, which the mentioned post seems to be a good starting point for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The approach described in this post is really nice but it is already advanced Scala programming. My advice, don't use it if you do not understand it.

2) `RoutedHttpService` is actually from the Eigengo's activator template not from the Spray API, you can find the source code [here](https://github.com/eigengo/activator-akka-spray/blob/master/src/main/scala/api/services.scala#L69).

3) You can also have a look at this [project](https://github.com/jacobus/s4), it gives a nice skeleton with less cake pattern composition.

Comment: Cheers, the link to the source is helpful, I wonder why it isn't in the blog post?! I actually implemented something much like his version while waiting for an answer, but had just assumed that it was something that was supposed to be 'out of the box' because no external source was mentioned. I didn't understand everything while going through the article, but since am fine with it all -- I learn best by going in at the deep end.